# Facebook Connect login box

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a problem with my code that is meant to create the Facebook Connect login popup.  In the code below, if I include the click event in my document ready then it triggers the creation of 2 popups, but if I leave it outside of the document ready then it fails to create any popup.  Can anybody advise?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {

                window.FB.init({ appId: 'xxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });

            });

            $('#fbLogin').click(function () {
                window.FB.login(function (response) {
                    if (response.status == 'connected') {
                        window.location.href = 'redirecturl';
                    }
                }, { perms: 'email' });
            });

        </script>
       <fb:login-button autologoutlink="false" perms="email" id="fbLogin">

       </fb:login-button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Clicking on `fb:login-button` will rise login dialog.
- Your binding on `#fblogin` will open second dialog

You need to choose one of `fb:login-button` or `FB.login` not both.

If you need page redirected once user is logged in just remove the `FB.login` call and subscribe ([`FB.Event.subscribe`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)) to `auth.statusChange` event to check login status.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response){
  if (response.status == 'connected') {
    window.location.href = 'redirecturl';
  }
});
```

Comment: This does not do the redirect I require.  My code is just the same except I replaced my original window.FB.login code block with your FB.Event.subscribe.  It logs in but does not redirect.

Comment: Ok, got it to work after moving the click event into the document.ready...thanks!